# (.NET 6) Cross-platform nuget library

Tags: c#, nuget, .net-6.0

I have a library that supports Windows and Linux. Each platform implementation has its own nuget package. The Windows package is referencing a windows TFM (`net6.0-windowsXX`) to make use of some UWP API. That obviously doesn't compile on Linux so I am conditionally targeting net6.0 and exchange the UWP implementation with some "null"/dummy implementation in that case:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(OS)' != 'Windows_NT' ">
  <TargetFrameworks>net6.0</TargetFrameworks>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(OS)' == 'Windows_NT' ">
  <TargetFrameworks>net6.0-windows10.0.17763.0</TargetFrameworks>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition="'$(OS)' == 'Windows_NT'">
  <Compile Remove="NullImpl.cs" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition="'$(OS)' != 'Windows_NT'">
  <Compile Remove="ActualImpl.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
```

I want users of the library to write code like that:

```
private static IImpl CreatePlatformImpl()
{
  if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux))
  {
    return new LinuxImpl();
  }

  if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows))
  {
    return new WindowsImpl();
  }

  throw new PlatformNotSupportedException();
}
```

Without having to conditionally exclude/include the platform implementations. However with the approach mentioned above I am still seeing compiler errors on Linux (it complains about missing UWP API). That makes me wonder when the `<Compile Remove />` is actually happening? I noticed that packaging the nuget (via `dotnet pack`) on Windows will have the proper implementation inside the respective Windows package whereas packaging it on Linux will not. So it seems this step is happening at "pack time" but not when the user is referencing the library. Maybe there's a better way to achieve this? Perhaps by using Runtime Identifiers?

Comment: You can publish a single NuGet package from a Windows machine that targets both TFM. Use compile time predefined constants to surround your Windows only code.

Comment: Your users will never be able to put both the conditional and the object creation in the same function, because all types named in the function are needed by the JIT compiler.

Comment: Same problem as https://stackoverflow.com/q/5233155/103167

Comment: High odds that you are doing battle with the IDE, its IntelliSense parser and code analyzer will produce red squiggles and error messages on this kind of code.  The IDE does not pay attention to Condition in the project file.  Consider #if to get ahead.

Comment: @LexLi You mean surround the whole windows impl class? That would mean that it's not visible on other platforms though and referencing it would give an error. My hope is that users can at least see the class, but not use any of its functions.